# Issue on AWS/GoDaddy DNS update - Not updating in Brazil

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, amazon-web-services, godaddy

I updated at 2:00AM (Brazilian Time) Route 53 and GoDaddy DNS info for my server,
trying to point the domain vitrina.cc to IP 184.72.238.163

I can access the site through the IP but through the domain name I can't.

I've done this before and it never took so long.
Is there any specific or general reason a DNS propagation could take so long?
Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Caching. Not to be too mean, but if you're asking this question you really need to buy and read [DNS and BIND](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do) so that you have a clear picture of how DNS works in the wild...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> vitrina.cc 
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:

Name:    vitrina.cc

Address:  184.72.238.163
```

Comment: Hi, @TheCleaner, Sorry, DNS newbie here. What does this mean exactly?

Comment: It means that vitrina.cc resolves to the IP you said you were changing it to according to Google's public DNS server.  Same holds true using 4.2.2.2, so it looks like your changes have taken by now.

Comment: That's the problem - vitrina.cc is still unacessible from where I'm connecting (Curitiba - Brazil). Never heard of such a large propagation time. Any idea why? :(

Comment: What DNS server is having the stale data?  You'd have to find out from them...the TTL might be long enough that they haven't cached it out yet and gotten the update.

Comment: AWS puts a default 172800 seconds TTL (48h). My concern is why some servers would update but not others. Testing DNSs through here (http://www.preshweb.co.uk/cgi-bin/dns-propagation-tracker.pl?domain=vitrina.cc&type=A&serversmode=random&servers=&nsdomain=) show that many don't even detect stale data, apparently

Comment: http://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/vitrina.cc - all that respond agree.  There's not much you can do but wait at least 48 hours.  Any DNS provider you talk to about it will give you the runaround until at least 48 hours.  The best thing in the future is to change the TTL to 1 hour a few days prior to making the change.  Then make the change and wait a day and set the TTL higher again.

Comment: Okay. Sucks but thanks for the help, @TheCleaner :)